# To split a page from a LaTeX document by keeping the document as produced by xdvipdfmx?

Tags: unix

This question evolved as a solution to the problem in old thread about *Copy-paste support for documents between Mac and Linux/Windows*.

I have these pdf commands in OS X

```
pdf180             pdfclose           pdfjam-pocketmod   pdfpun
pdf270             pdfcrop            pdfjam-slides3up   pdfroff
pdf2dsc            pdfcslatex         pdfjam-slides6up   pdftex
pdf2ps             pdfcsplain         pdfjoin            pdftosrc
pdf90              pdfetex            pdflatex           pdfxmltex
pdfannotextractor  pdfflip            pdfmex             
pdfatfi            pdfjadetex         pdfnup             
pdfbook            pdfjam             pdfopen
```

where nothing comes to my mind as a helpful tool.

**How can you split a page from a LaTeX document by keeping the document as produced by xdvipdfmx?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way which does not rely on external tools. `pagesel` can be used to typeset one or more pages from a document. To create the document, comment out the line which loads `pagesel` and compile until everything is correct. Then uncomment the line and recompile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[3]{pagesel}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

This will get you just page 3:

[image: page 3]

If you prefer an external tool, `pdftk` is excellent but is not, I think, being maintained any longer. However, it is still the best command line tool I'm familiar with.

Comment: I understood the question in the way, that the OP wants to split the page itself, i.e. cutting a part of the page only, not selecting a full page. But perhaps it's way you wrote ;-)

Comment: This is what I want. @cfr I had to comment out the package **natbib** because its use lead to some error.

Comment: @cfr I opened a new thread about the error when you use **natbib** together with **pagesel** http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226159/13173