# To control Appearance of citations with natbib and pagesel

Tags: natbib, pagesel

Minimum Tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[1]{pagesel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
Its study has resulted in various methods, \cite{jiapu, suppappola, kadambe, benitez, christov2, portet}, where some are based on the time-frequency analysis and the other on wavelet analysis.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

The solution of splitting pages from a document by *pagesel*, thread [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226156/13173), caused another problem with references. 
If I use the package *pagesel*, it seems that I cannot use *natbib* because I get an error:

```
LaTeX Error: \makeindex undefined. (\renewcommand\makeindex ...)
```

and warnings

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `physionet_amplitude' on page 3 undefined on i
nput line 202.       
LaTeX Warning: Reference `table:frequency_artifacts' on page 3 undefined on inp
ut line 220.      
LaTeX Warning: Reference `table:artifacts' on page 3 undefined on input line 22
9.
```

My references with `\usepackage{natbib}`

[image]

My references without *natbib*

[image]

where the lines expands out of margin, which I do not want.

This suggests me that *natbib* has an effect to the representation of the references too.
However

**Which packages are good for references but also for splitting pages from document at the same time?**

Comment: Sorry but I doubt that you tested your "mininum tex" document. Such documents are not for decoration. They should allow others to reproduce your problem, so always test them carefully.

Comment: There are still two `\begin{document}` in the example. Beside this: load pagesel after natbib, or try the option files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right. Why does the *natbib* must be before *pagesel*?

Comment: pagesel issues a `\nofiles` which sets `\makeindex` to `\relax` and natbib doesn't like this (imho a natbib problem).

Comment: You have to compile your document without `pagesel` and only after that you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers and explanations in comments.

Ulrike Fisher

> pagesel issues a \nofiles which sets \makeindex to \relax and natbib doesn't like this (imho a natbib problem). –  Ulrike Fischer Feb 2 at 18:14

egreg

> Compile document without pagesel and only that you can use it.